# Como trabajar con una base de datos desde una VPN?

Tags: sql-server, vpn

Como equipo de estudiantes de desarrollo queremos trabajar con una base de datos de SQLServer. Por esa razón no puede usarse un servidor local... como se podría hacer desde una vpn?? Es decir, a qué servidor se debe "apuntar" para que todos los miembros del equipo accedan a dicha base de datos??

Comment: La respuesta que te dieron es la respuesta correcta. A eso sólo añadiría que es conveniente que revises, al menos en principio, cómo funciona una VPN para que entiendas por qué _automágicamente_ caes en la red local del servidor.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Así voy a hacer... me pongo en búsqueda de dicha información

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes apuntar a la ip local del servidor donde se encuentre alojada la base de datos, ya que al momento que tu te conectas a una VPN, tu eres parte de esa red local y se te asigna a tu máquina una ip privada.